# condensing SQL SELECT statements and returning larger data set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables. the Album Table and the Club table. ClubID in the Album table is a foreign key in reference to the primary key ClubID in the Club table. NumImg means number of images in an album.

```
Album Table

NumImg  Date        ClubID
------  ----        ------
100 2015-08-01  1
300 2015-08-01  2
350 2015-08-01  3
200 2015-07-31  1
250 2015-07-31  2
400 2015-07-30  3
500 2015-07-30  4

Club Table

ClubID  ClubName
------  ---------
1   bloke
2   luxy entertainment complex
3   t2 lounge
4   gravity
```

I am able to execute each of the 5 SQL statements below to get the numbers which I added at the end of the statements (after the equals).

```
SELECT Album.NumImg FROM Album,Club where Album.ClubID=Club.ClubID and Album.Date="2015-08-01" and Club.ClubName="bloke" = 100
SELECT Album.NumImg FROM Album,Club where Album.ClubID=Club.ClubID and Album.Date="2015-08-01" and Club.ClubName="luxy entertainment complex" = 300
SELECT Album.NumImg FROM Album,Club where Album.ClubID=Club.ClubID and Album.Date="2015-08-01" and Club.ClubName="t2 lounge" = 350
SELECT Album.NumImg FROM Album,Club where Album.ClubID=Club.ClubID and Album.Date="2015-07-31" and Club.ClubName="bloke" = 200
SELECT Album.NumImg FROM Album,Club where Album.ClubID=Club.ClubID and Album.Date="2015-07-31" and Club.ClubName="luxy entertainment complex" = 250
```

What I want to do in an attempt to lower processing time is to try to condense this into one single SQL statement and return multiple numbers as a result and processing that instead of making separate calls for each number.

The inputs required to receive a number are the club name and the date of the album. Those can change at any time.

Does anyone know how I can modify my SQL statements shown above to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL permits an `IN ()` expression to operate on multiple columns, grouped by `()` and separated by commas. So you may list your many conditions inside a single `IN ()` clause, whereby each pair of columns must match the pair of of conditions.

```
SELECT 
  NumImg,
  Date,
  ClubName
FROM
  album
  INNER JOIN club ON album.ClubID = club.ClubID
WHERE 
  (Date, ClubName) IN (
    ('2015-08-01', 'bloke'),
    ('2015-08-01', 'luxy entertainment complex'),
    ('2015-08-01','t2 lounge'),
    ('2015-07-31', 'bloke'),
    ('2015-07-31', 'luxy entertainment complex')
)
```

Here's a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dc54/2

I have included the `Date` and `ClubName` in the `SELECT` list to make it easier to differentiate them in the final result set. I have also replaced your implicit inner join (comma-separated tables in `FROM`) with an explicit `INNER JOIN`, as that is a more modern syntax.

Note that this could also be expressed as a chain of conditions grouped by `AND` and `OR`. The multicolumn `IN ()` is much tidier and the two likely have the exact same performance.

```
WHERE
  (Date = '2015-08-01' AND ClubName = 'bloke')
  OR (Date = '2015-08-01' AND ClubName = 'luxy entertainment complex')
  OR...
```

#### Addendum

Without somthing to sort on in an `ORDER BY`, there is no way to force the rows to return in the order you specified the conditions. You could use your original set of queries and execute them together with `UNION ALL`. That should return them in the specified order, but a segment matching no rows won't return empty.

```
SELECT Album.NumImg FROM Album,Club where Album.ClubID=Club.ClubID and Album.Date="2015-08-01" and Club.ClubName="bloke"
UNION ALL
SELECT Album.NumImg FROM Album,Club where Album.ClubID=Club.ClubID and Album.Date="2015-08-01" and Club.ClubName="luxy entertainment complex"
UNION ALL
etc...
```

It could also be done by listing the conditions once again in `ORDER BY` inside a `CASE` that returns a literal value to sort them:

```
WHERE 
  (Date, ClubName) IN (
    ('2015-08-01', 'bloke'),
    ('2015-08-01', 'luxy entertainment complex'),
    ('2015-08-01','t2 lounge'),
    ('2015-07-31', 'bloke'),
    ('2015-07-31', 'luxy entertainment complex')
)
-- Hack to force the positions, likely to be slow....
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN Date = '2015-08-01' AND ClubName = 'bloke' THEN 1
  WHEN Date = '2015-08-01' AND ClubName = 'luxy entertainment complex' THEN 2
  WHEN Date = '2015-08-01' AND ClubName = 't2 lounge' THEN 3
  ...
  ...
  ELSE 99999
END ASC
```

Comment: I didn't think one could use multiple columns with `IN`. I'll try that and see what I can come up with

Comment: Also, is there a way I can return the data in the order I request it with one statement because I can receive the results in the order I want by issuing individual selects but is there a keyword or something that allows me to receive the data in the same order using one SQL statement?

Comment: @Mike You can't force these to return in a specific order. You could use your original set of multiple queries and instead of executing them separately, connect each by `UNION ALL`. That would get you the desired order, but not the performance gain of combining them with `IN ()`.

Comment: I suppose you could specify the conditions again in an `ORDER BY` with `CASE` but that's not going to be fast either, and super ugly. Added above

Comment: I wish I could be hired in the field just for coming up with good questions. If only there was a golden solution. Just thinking of union and using cases is probably not gonna make the query run any faster.

Comment: @Mike Well, assuming you will construct the query dynamically with some programming language, you should have a data structure representing the input value pairs. You could use that structure (array, whatever) in the order it's in to locate the result in the result set.

Comment: I have tried that and the wrong data is returned. Sometimes the same club name applies to different dates and sometimes the same date applies to different club names.

Comment: @Mike It's unclear what you tried. Using my first query, you can index the output rowset by the _combination_ of date-clubname in application code. Do you use PHP or something to build this? I may not get back to this until tomorrow, but the first query has everything needed to reconstruct the desired order

Comment: @Mike ^^ ...meaning that if while fetching rows, you create an array/hash (structure with string keys) where the keys are a concatenation `"<date>_<clubname>"` and the array value is the `NumImg`, then when you loop over your original data structure of pairs, concatenate them also to `"<date>_<clubname>"` and use that as an index to your array. It returns `NumImg`. How you implement this is language-specific.

Comment: @Mike Did you make progress with your sort? If you'd like, please ping me here or link into chat so we can resolve/complete/accept your question to your satisfaction.

Comment: Not yet but I'm considering caching output of the individual statements and using the cache until data changes.